# "Oh, dear!" vs. "Oh dear!"

Tags: punctuation, commas, interjections

Which is correct, "Oh, dear!" or "Oh dear!"?

My understanding is that the word *oh* is an interjection, and should thus be followed by a comma. However, is the second usage the correct one because the two words form a phrase and the word dear is not a vocative here?

Comment: It's conventional to put a comma after interjections, but not meaningful.  Me, I'd put it in if I wanted a reading with a rising cadence, putting more stress on *dear* than on *Oh*, and leave it out if I wanted a 'falling' cadence, sort of "OHdear". But I write mostly for actors.

Answer (score 8):

The Google Books results come out quite strongly in favor of omitting the comma, but it depends on how long the “Oh . . .” phrase is.  Two-word versions usually do not have it, while longer ones like “Oh for the love of . . .” more often do.

You should inspect these for yourself.  I went the first twenty pages of “Oh dear”, and certainly found some with the comma.  Not many, but some.

**Shorter ones:**

- [Oh dear](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+dear%22&oq=%22oh+dear%22&gs_l=serp.3...76682.77257.14.77682.4.4.0.0.0.0.94.234.4.4.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.-1SaUWeQMPM&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh dear me](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22oh,+dear%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+dear+me%22&oq=%22oh+dear+me%22&gs_l=serp.3...32027.32091.3.32325.2.2.0.0.0.1.99.181.2.2.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.-H1wS4g7_04&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh dear God](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22oh,+dear%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+dear+god%22&oq=%22oh+dear+god%22&gs_l=serp.3...1803491.1803802.2.1803963.4.4.0.0.0.2.116.346.2j2.4.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.MJPcKySQBgs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh God](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+God%22&oq=%22oh+God%22&gs_l=serp.3...23892.23906.15.23919.3.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.sLk9HlKNZUI&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh yes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+yes%22&oq=%22oh+yes%22&gs_l=serp.3..0l2.30770.30781.16.31022.3.2.1.0.0.1.206.323.0j1j1.2.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.DLt3uBEFJsM&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh no](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+no%22&oq=%22oh+no%22&gs_l=serp.3...21938.21985.17.22236.2.0.2.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.cesh..0.0...1.1._JUxANy42vs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh crap](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+crap%22&oq=%22oh+crap%22&gs_l=serp.3...25985.26364.18.26523.4.4.0.0.0.0.95.234.4.4.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.WFZa3H1BSVA&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh hell](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+hell%22&oq=%22oh+hell%22&gs_l=serp.3...21868.22198.19.22612.4.4.0.0.0.1.116.315.2j2.4.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.YYkgXd38Rcs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh shit](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+shit%22&oq=%22oh+shit%22&gs_l=serp.3...23798.24093.20.24245.4.4.0.0.0.2.131.412.2j2.4.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.2z3VQYM085w&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh fuck](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+fuck%22&oq=%22oh+fuck%22&gs_l=serp.3...22756.23012.21.23262.4.0.4.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.o6EjcPmMIxo&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)

**Longer ones:**

- [Oh no you don’t](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+no+you+don%27t%22&oq=%22oh+no+you+don%27t%22&gs_l=serp.3...32420.33768.22.33898.12.8.2.0.0.1.124.549.6j2.8.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.GoBfjSlo-Xw&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh for goodness’ sake](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+for+goodness+sake%22&oq=%22oh+for+goodness+sake%22&gs_l=serp.3...26103.30037.13.30349.18.9.7.0.0.1.685.1166.7j1j5-1.9.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.MdfiuohchWM&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh my goodness](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+my+goodness%22&oq=%22oh+my+goodness%22&gs_l=serp.3...183764.187087.7.187255.17.4.13.0.0.2.146.408.2j2.4.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.jI4KED69QyM&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh for God’s sake](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+for+god%27s+sake%22&oq=%22oh+for+god%27s+sake%22&gs_l=serp.3...38044.39186.12.39338.7.6.1.0.0.1.104.411.5j1.6.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.hXnNy6q2IG4&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh for fuck’s sake](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+for+fuck%27s+sake%22&oq=%22oh+for+fuck%27s+sake%22&gs_l=serp.3...97425.100540.11.100702.19.13.6.0.0.3.138.961.11j2.13.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.BFmEANJ59pM&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh my heavens](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+my+heavens%22&oq=%22oh+my+heavens%22&gs_l=serp.3...19532.20776.8.20924.7.7.0.0.0.0.82.413.7.7.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.EAPVSEMHqSw&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh for Pete’s sake](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+for+pete%27s+sake%22&oq=%22oh+for+pete%27s+sake%22&gs_l=serp.3...9646.9924.10.10142.4.4.0.0.0.2.132.412.2j2.4.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.8tbTQWRF5ME&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)
- [Oh for the love of](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oh+yeah%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&biw=1088&bih=721&tbm=bks&ei=6-FoUL-mD8_ryAGU1IBA&start=20&sa=N#hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22oh+for+the+love+of%22&oq=%22oh+for+the+love+of%22&gs_l=serp.3...91208.92581.6.92821.15.13.1.0.0.5.130.1142.8j5.13.0.cesh..0.0...1.1.nkxAvh4wtMg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e20a734769ea1fd6&biw=1088&bih=721)

As you can see, there are exceptions, but most do not use use the comma after the *oh*.  One old but interesting examples is the line from Shakespeare’s *All’s Well That Ends Well*, because you can find it variously punctuated.

- O, for the love of laughter, let him fetch his drum;
- Oh, for the love of laughter, let him fetch his drum ;
- Oh ! for the love of laughter, let him fetch his drum ;

The old hymn doesn’t usually use a comma, either:

- O for a thousand tongues to sing my dear Redeemer's praise

I suggest omitting the comma, but I don’t know that there is an actual rule here to cite.

Answer (score 1):

The OED mentions "Oh dear" without a comma.  I can't say I've ever seen it with one.

Answer (score 1):

"Oh" itself is an exclamation and can be followed by a comma, which could also be an exclamation mark; besides, you can make other exclamations using "Oh" as a starter ("Oh yeah!" could exemplify this). I would like to share some examples taken from the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/oh):

1) Used when you are reacting to something that has been said, especially if you did not know it before:

- ‘I saw Ben yesterday.’ **‘Oh yes, how is he?’**
- **Oh dear!** What's happened now?
- You can't come tonight? **Oh well**, see you next week then.
- ‘Emma has a new job.’ **‘Oh, has she?’**

2) Used to express surprise, fear, joy, etc.:

- **Oh, how wonderful!**
- **Oh no, I've broken it!**

3) Used to attract somebody's attention:

- **Oh, Sue!** Could you help me a moment?

The position of the punctuation marks must vary as the intention (emphasis) of the speaker/writer varies; thus, "Oh, no! I've broken it!" and "Oh no, I've broken it!" are both correct.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

> Oh dear what can the matter be
>   Oh dear what can the matter be
>   Oh dear what can the matter be
>   Johnny so long at the fair
>   He'll buy me some Bonnie blue ribbon
>   He'll buy me some Bonnie blue ribbon
>   He'll buy me some Bonnie blue ribbon
>   To tie up my Bonnie brown hair

As you can see in this song it is just Oh dear! And not Oh, dear! But I have seen it both ways